# Standard folder for .so files

Tags: dll, ubuntu, directory, structure, shared-libraries

Where should I put .so files in Ubuntu. In other words, what is the standard/convention for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/usr/lib is the folder for [Libraries for the binaries in /usr/bin/ and /usr/sbin/](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard). /usr/local/lib is the tertiary structure for binaries specific to the machine.